# Flutter My app Not Instant Get Name User In Dasboard When Login & First Open App

Tags: flutter, authentication, events, logic

when i login it's will say welcome, username. but i got empty name, this is also happen when i first login apps. when i click other navigation and back to home it's get the name.

this is the picture my apps :

- [first time login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx210.jpg)
- [after i click other navbottom and back to home again (my username is 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/952hJ.jpg)

code when login :

```
void loginToApss() async{
    try{
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(Api.login),
          body: {
            'email' : _controllerEmail.text,
            'password' : _controllerPassword.text
          }
      );
      if(response.statusCode==200){
        var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if(responseBody['success']){
          InfoMessage.snackbar(Get.context!, 'Login Berasil');
          User user = User.fromJson(responseBody['data']);
          await EventPref.saveUser(user);
          Get.off(() => Dasboard());

        }else{
          InfoMessage.snackbar(Get.context!, 'Pasword atau Email Salah');
        }
      }
    }catch(e){
      InfoMessage.snackbar(Get.context!,'Koneksi Gagal');
      // InfoMessage.snackbar(Get.context!, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

code in dasboard :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart';
import 'package:gym/api/Asset.dart';
import 'package:gym/controller/c_user.dart';

import 'fragment_gym.dart';
import 'fragment_home.dart';
import 'fragment_kalori.dart';
import 'fragment_tips.dart';

class Dasboard extends StatelessWidget {

  CUser _cUser = Get.put(CUser());
  RxInt _index = 0.obs;

  final List<Widget> _fragments = [
    FragmentHome(),
    FragmentGym(),
    FragmentTipsGym(),
    FragmentKalori()
  ];

  final List _navs = [
    {
      'icon_on': Icons.home,
      'icon_off': Icons.home_outlined,
      'label': 'Home'
    },
    {
      'icon_on': Icons.bookmark,
      'icon_off': Icons.bookmark_border,
      'label': 'Gym'
    },
    {
      'icon_on': FontAwesomeIcons.boxOpen,
      'icon_off': FontAwesomeIcons.box,
      'label': 'Tips Gym'
    },
    {
      'icon_on': Icons.web,
      'icon_off': Icons.web_outlined,
      'label': 'Kalori'
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder(
        init: CUser(),
        initState: (state){
          _cUser.getUser();
        },
        builder: (controller){
          return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Obx(() => _fragments[_index.value]),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Obx(() => BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: _index.value,
                onTap: (value) => _index.value = value,
                selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Asset.colorTextTitle
                ),
                showSelectedLabels: true,
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                selectedItemColor: Asset.colorTextTitle,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,

                items: List.generate(4, (index) {
                  var nav = _navs[index];
                  return BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(nav['icon_off']),
                      label: nav['label'],
                      activeIcon: Icon(nav['icon_on'])
                  );
                })
            ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

controller user :

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:gym/model/user.dart';
import 'package:gym/event/event.pref.dart';


class CUser extends GetxController {
  Rx<User> _user = User(0, '', '', '','').obs;

  User get user => _user.value;

  void getUser() async {
    if(_user == User(0, '', '', '','')){
      User? user = await EventPref.getUser();
      _user.value = user!;
    }else{
      User? user = await EventPref.getUser();
      _user.value = user!;
    }

  }

}
```

model user :

```
class User {
  int idUser;
  String nama;
  String email;
  String no_telp;
  String password;


  User(this.idUser, this.nama, this.email,this.no_telp, this.password);

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    int.parse(json['id_user']),
    json['nama'],
    json['email'],
    json['no_telp'],
    json['password'],

  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id_user': this.idUser.toString(),
    'nama': this.nama,
    'email': this.email,
    'no_telp': this.no_telp,
    'password': this.password,
  };

}
```

in homeFragment :

```
                    Text(
                      _cUser.user.nama,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Asset.colorTextTitle,
                          fontSize: 32,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
```

Comment: obx will update when obs variable is changed, try to print your variable changed or not

Comment: i print in dasboard it's print empty, but if iam print in controller it's print 1. i still confuse how to fix it

Comment: i just fix it, iam wrap text with obx